# Rails write to a already open live SSE stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails, you can create a SSE(sever sent event) stream like this in a controller:

```
class MyController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionController::Live

  def index
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    sse = SSE.new(response.stream, retry: 300, event: "event-name")
    sse.write({ name: 'John'})
    sse.write({ name: 'John'}, id: 10)
    sse.write({ name: 'John'}, id: 10, event: "other-event")
    sse.write({ name: 'John'}, id: 10, event: "other-event", retry: 500)
  ensure
    sse.close
  end
end
```

What I'd like to do is write to this stream from another route, like this example in sinatra below. In all the rails examples I've seen, they use a queue based on redis, which seems overkill for something like this and can easily be accomplished in Sinatra.

A example of what I would like to do is this, using Sinatra instead of Rails:

```
get '/connect', provides: 'text/event-stream' do
    stream :keep_open do |out|
      connections << out

      #out.callback on stream close evt. 
      out.callback {
        #delete the connection 
        connections.delete(out)
      }
    end
  end

 post '/push' do
    connections.each { |out| out << "data: hi!"}
  end
```

Thanks for the help!